# What is, by police standards, considered legally walking versus riding bicycle?

Tags: safety, california

Legally, what berkeley, california police based legal standard for walking bicycle in the residential neighborhood street? Walking with the bicycle at the side, and, or, walking while bicycle is underneath, and, or straddling the bicycle, with both feet on the ground while walking with it? Please define clearly, with website references, videos, and, or, graphics, please?

Comment: Reading between the lines, sounds like you need a lawyer well versed in  berkeley, california transport law, not the internet.

Comment: This may help: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35833/cycle-law-definition-of-dismounting

Comment: I realise the duplicate is not technically answering the question, but since the answer is "I used a search engine to find the legislation and here it is"... we are not here for that.

Comment: What "residential neighborhood street" in Berkeley has a walk your bicycle rule? I know the University has those signs. I also know the commercial area in Berkeley has those signs, but I don't ever remember seeing a residential area in Berkeley having those signs. Can you tell us exactly where this happened in Berkeley. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. In Berkeley, nowhere on the signs does it say to "dismount" your bike. It only says to "walk your bike". I think this distinction is important.

Answer (score 1):

You were probably fined under the California Vehicle Code [21113(f)](http://www.leginfo.ca.gov/cgi-bin/displaycode?section=veh&group=21001-22000&file=21100-21117) which doesn't specify what you're asking.

However, this is not the final source and I am still waiting to hear whether this happened on campus grounds, or in a commercial city zone, because I don't remember seeing these signs in any "residential area neighborhood" in Berkeley.

> (f) A transit development board may adopt ordinances, rules, or
>   regulations to restrict, or specify the conditions for, the use of
>   bicycles, motorized bicycles, electric bicycles, skateboards,
>   electrically motorized boards, and roller skates on property under the
>   control of, or any portion of property used by, the board.
>
> (g) A
>   public agency, including, but not limited to, the Regents of the
>   University of California and the Trustees of the California State
>   University, may adopt rules or regulations to restrict, or specify the
>   conditions for, the use of bicycles, motorized bicycles, electric
>   bicycles, skateboards, electrically motorized boards, and roller
>   skates on public property under the jurisdiction of that agency.
>
> (h) "Housing authority," for the purposes of this section, means a
>   housing authority located within a county with a population of over
>   6,000,000 people, and any other housing authority that complies with
>   the requirements of this section.
>
> (i) "Public transportation
>   agency," for purposes of this section, means a public agency that
>   provides public transportation as defined in paragraph (1) of
>   subdivision (f) of Section 1 of Article XIX A of the California
>   Constitution.
>
> [...]

Comment: That's a great first answer - thank you.  Your comment asking for an exact location is excellent thinking too.  Keep up the good answers!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.calbike.org/bicycling_in_california_sharing_the_road  In Berkeley you may ride anywhere, except certain prohibited areas or where you would impede the flow of traffic, each city in CA has different rules on sidewalks that vary and are can apply to only certain sidewalks or all, or a mix. You can walk a bike in each ways you described except places like interstate highways where you can't walk. Warning: laws being what they may, you could run into a cop who doesn't care, is ignorant of the law, or is simply a sociopath that enjoys ruining your day.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but I thought I'd hazard a guess at why: it's because this doesn't actually answer the question. See [answer]. Cheers

Comment: I thought I explained that where its legal to walk its legal to walk a bike and in every way she described. I think the cop warning is what earned me my down vote. Walking a bike down the street while straddling it could earn you a 72 psych hold in some areas.